# Add tab spaces to mail body

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to add a tab/spacing to the body of my text, specifically before and after the "1."

I tried " " and Space(10).

```
 sBodyStart = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"" color=""black"">" & _
                "Good Afternoon," & "<br>" & "<br>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Please confirm and acknowledge the below by responding with the appropriate voting button." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"1. Do not share this information." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Please provide a response to this email using the voting buttons, no later than September 20, 2019. If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to reach out." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "</font>"
```

Comment: This is going out to HTML and will be intrepreted as such. I suspect your HTML interpreter (outlook) is stripping multiple spaces as HTML generally does that. Try tossing an `&nbsp;` in the string for each space you wish to add.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually HTML embedded into the VBA, which will ignore whitespace. Should work if you add `"&nbsp;"`

Comment: How would I add it in? I've tried "1." "&nbsp;" "&nbsp;" "&nbsp;" "&nbsp;" "Do not share this Information", but that isn't working

Comment: Add it as a string literal in VBA: `"1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do not share this information."` The confusing part here is that you are concatenating your string together in VBA using VBA characters like `vbcrlf` and possible `vbtab`. That's going to be interpreted when it makes your `sBodyStart` variable. But then that variable is going to be used to write an email... so Outlook or the end-users email client is going to interpret the HTML you have in that string, and that's where you are losing your spaces (probably). So just like you need `<br>` to tell it "New line" you also need `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

How about some html entitys like:

```
 &nbsp; to add a single space.
 &ensp; to add 2 spaces.
 &emsp; to add 4 spaces.
 or some  other "special" char from unicode ?
```

Might be possible to make outlooks life a bit more interesting by trying

```
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vbTab` or `Chr(9)`

If you use `Space(10)`, then it will put in 10 spaces.  Outlook has a nasty habit of "correcting" excess spaces, either eliminating them entirely, or converting them to Non Breaking Spaces (`Chr(160)`)

Comment: I did the following, and it didn't show a tab "1." & vbTab & "Do not share this information" & "<br>" & _

Comment: @rauf741 Have you set your `Ruler.TabStops`?

Comment: I haven't, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It works like a charm for me. You can adjust the margin amount as needed

`<p style='margin-left:36.0pt'>Your Text Here</p>`